# Liste de mots français avec accents?

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources, linguistique

Sur [ce site](https://www.listesdemots.net/mots7lettres.htm), il y a des listes de mots français d'une longueur donnée. C'est très bien. Mais, pour moi, il y a un problème majeur - il n'y a pas d'accents sur les mots. C'est carrément une abomination!

Existe-t-il un site (j'ai cherché sans succès) similaire avec des mots français **avec accents**?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134730/discussion-on-question-by-verace-liste-de-mots-francais-avec-accents).

Comment: I have locked this question for 1 day due to disputes in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce n'est pas une abomination, listedemots.net est un site dédié aux joueurs de Scrabble pour lequel les accents ne sont pas pris en compte.

Le site [lexique.org](http://www.lexique.org/) permet d'interroger une base de  140000 mots et d'extraire par exemple tous ceux d'une longueur donnée :

[image]

Comment: Je constate que la liste est alphabétique et les mots sont par longeur selon cette alphabétisation.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a Linux system, the `wfrench` package will install a list of nearly 40,000 french words (including accents):

```
$ grep -E '^.{7}$' /usr/share/dict/french | head
à-côtés
à-coups
à-venir
abacule
abaissa
abaissé
abaisse
abajoue
abandon
abatage

$ grep -E '^.{7}$' /usr/share/dict/french | tail
zwanzés
zwanzez
zyeutai
zyeutas
zyeutât
zyeutée
zyeuter
zyeutes
zyeutés
zyeutez
```

(If not, I could e-mail the file to you.)